# Passing an additional parameter with an onChange event

Tags: reactjs, onchange

**What I'm trying to do:**

I am trying to pass a string from a child component to the handleChange function of a parent component.

**What currently works:**

I have a parent React JS class with the following method:

```
handleChange(event) {

    console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

In the render function I have the following:

```
<Child handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

In the Child class I have:

```
<fieldset onChange={this.props.handleChange}>
    <div>Tag 1: <input id="tag1" value={tags[0]} /></div>
    <div>Tag 2: <input id="tag2" value={tags[1]} /></div>
    <div>Tag 3: <input id="tag3" value={tags[2]} /></div>
</fieldset>
```

This works fine.

**What I am trying to do instead:**

I am attempting to add a `section` parameter to the handleChange function as follows:

```
handleChange(section, event) {
    console.log(section);
    console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

And in the Child class I have:

```
<fieldset onChange={this.props.handleChange("tags")}>
    <div>Tag 1: <input id="tag1" value={tags[0]} /></div>
    <div>Tag 2: <input id="tag2" value={tags[1]} /></div>
    <div>Tag 3: <input id="tag3" value={tags[2]} /></div>
</fieldset>
```

I now get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

This error is being thrown in my second console.log statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I am considering making the `section` parameter optional. If so, is there an easy way to do this? It seems like it might not be possible if the event parameter needs to be last.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri This is not a duplicate of this question since I am trying to pass the parameter from the child class to the parent class. Because of that I cannot specify the variable in the onChange attribute of the <Child ...> element because it cannot see the variable inside of the child component.

Comment: Ok Understood, I will remove the close vote.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

When you are writing this:

```
<fieldset onChange={this.props.handleChange("tags")}>
```

`handleChange` will be called immediately as soon as render is triggered.

Instead, do it like this:

```
<fieldset onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChange("tags", e)}>
```

Now the `handleChange` will be called when `onChange` handler is called.

Comment: I may be mistaken but using arrow function (or .bind) as a prop is bad practice and could have performance implications. Explained here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

Answer (score 23):

In your handle event use double arrow function, there's no need to bind when using arrow function:

```
handleChange = tags => (event) => {
    console.log(tags);
    console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

And in the Child:

```
<fieldset onChange={this.props.handleChange("tags")}>
    <div>Tag 1: <input id="tag1" value={tags[0]} /></div>
    <div>Tag 2: <input id="tag2" value={tags[1]} /></div>
    <div>Tag 3: <input id="tag3" value={tags[2]} /></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Note this currently requires babel plugin "transform-class-properties"

Answer (score 10):

```
const handleChange = (tags) => (event) => {
// console.log(tags);
// console.log(event.target.value);
};

<input
      type="text"
      name="name"
      placeholder="Name"
      value={input.Iname}
      onChange={handleChange("Iname")}
    />
```

Answer (score 8):

As the OP, I had originally posted this as a follow up on my question, but it was deleted and I was told to post it as an answer instead, so here it is:

Based on Ritesh Bansal's answer, I have learned the following:

The following line was not working because when using parenthesis after the function name, the function is called immediately rather than waiting for a change to happen:

```
<fieldset onChange={this.props.handleChange("tags")}>
```

The above will not work, neither would a function such as this:

```
<fieldset onChange={this.props.handleChange()}>
```

The above would also get called immediately on first render.

There are two solutions to this:

The not-so good way:

```
<fieldset onChange={this.props.handleChange.bind(this, "tags")}>
```

The much better way:

```
<fieldset onChange={(evt) => this.props.handleChange("tags", evt)}>
```

The problem is now solved. Thank you everyone!

Update:

I also researched Shubham Khatri's suggestion to change the child element to this:

```
<Child handleChange={(e,val) => this.handleChange(e, val)}/>
```

I did not realize that using `bind` in the render function, that every time render is called it creates a new function instance. I can, therefore, either use Shubham Khatri's method, or bind the methods in the constructor.

Comment: <fieldset onChange={this.props.handleChange.bind(this, "tags")}>,  is the best way, when optimisation is in mind, just that your binding should be inside the constructor function

Comment: Doing (e, val) => this.handleChange(e, val) is the same as doing as my answer. In both cases a function returns another function.

Answer (score 7):

**No anonymous function defined on each render()**:

Most of the answers here recommend an anonymous function defined in render(), which, as Davidicus pointed out, is not recommended: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

François's answer avoids that problem, but as Vael Victus pointed out, that requires `transform-class-properties`.

However, what he's doing is just defining a function which defines a function, which you can otherwise do like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = (yourSpecialParam) => (event) => this.handleChange(yourSpecialParam).bind(this)
}

render() {
  return <button onClick={this.handleChange(1234)} >Click Me</button>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to pass a param from the child component to the parent you can take an argument to the arrow function.

```
handleChange(event, section) {
    console.log(section);
    console.log(event.target.value);
}
<Child handleChange={(e, val) => this.handleChange(e, val)} />

<fieldset onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChange(e, "tags")}>
    <div>Tag 1: <input id="tag1" value={tags[0]} /></div>
    <div>Tag 2: <input id="tag2" value={tags[1]} /></div>
    <div>Tag 3: <input id="tag3" value={tags[2]} /></div>
</fieldset>
```

Sample snippet

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  handleChange(e, val) {
    console.log(e.target.value, val);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <Child handleChange={(e,val) => this.handleChange(e, val)}/>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return(
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChange(e, 'tab')}/>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to having an arrow function in the <Child ... /> element over what I had already?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<fieldset onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChange("tags", e)}>
    <div>Tag 1: <input id="tag1" value={tags[0]} /></div>
    <div>Tag 2: <input id="tag2" value={tags[1]} /></div>
    <div>Tag 3: <input id="tag3" value={tags[2]} /></div>
</fieldset>
```